# Reference table rows with shifting index in LaTeX

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, longtable, indexing

I am conducting a series of interviews with person A,B,C,D ect.

I have prepared an "interview model", with question I'm going to ask (Every question is labeled with 1,2,3,4) (Table questions and explanations)

Lets say I interview person A, every question I ask person A will be labeled QA.1,QA.2,QA.3 ect. "Q" stands for question and "A" corresponds to interview person A and "1" corresponds to question 1 in the "Interview model". 
Every answer will be labeled AA.1,AA.2,AA.3 ect. First "A" stands for answer second "A" corresponds to interview person A and "1" corresponds to question 1 in the "Interview model".

Questions and answers will always alternate, but and unexpected follow up question can occur.

Lets say I ask a follow up question (which is not in the "Interviewmodel") this question should be labled as a sub question to the previously asked qustion (in this case QA.1) this sub question should then be labled as QA1.a. And it's answer as AA.1.a.

If I asked another sub question it should be labeled QA.1.b ect. (answer AA.1.b)

In question 10 (QA.10) I could ask yet another follow up question which then should be labeled QA.10.a. This is repeated for person B (QB.1,AB.1, QB.2, AB.2,QB.3,AB.3,QB.3.a,AB.3.a) and C (QC.1,AC.1,QC.2,AC.2,QC.2.a,AC.2.a ect)

Thereby all the "interview model questions" and the result questions/answers are directly linked, and unexpected follow up questions are labeled as sub questions to the previously asked "interview model question"

Thank you very much for your time!

[image]

Please note that parts of the code was made by Christian Hupfer
Link: [Reference table row in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356815/reference-table-row-in-latex)

Also this is a simplified version of the real interview (which is way longer) therefor a longtable is used.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[top=2.81cm, bottom=2.75cm,right=2cm, left=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
   \onehalfspacing
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{V}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\makeatother
\newcounter{rowcntr}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}c}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{rowcntr}{0}\setcounter{subquestion}{0}}

\begin{document}


\section*{Interview questions (Interview model))}
The following table contains my interview questions and explanation

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|N| c | V{7.6cm} | V{7.6cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Question}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Explanation}} \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Interview phase 1}\\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|C{17.5cm}|}{\textit{Text This phase focus on ...TextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextText  }}\\ \hline
   \label{que:1} & A & Do you think ...? & This is a good question.\\
   \label{que:2} & C & Do you feel? & This is a good question.\\
   \label{que:3} & E & What do you think of your previous boss & Relationship between employee and employer text Text textText text Text text Text text.\\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Interview phase 2}\\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|C{17.5cm}|}{\textit{Text This phase focus on ... }}\\ \hline
   \label{que:4} & D & Is this ...? & Good question.\\
   \label{que:5} & I & Do you like Text  & A good question.\\ \hline

   \caption {Questions and explanation} \label{tab:interviewspg}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\section*{Interview answers person A}
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|c| V{16.5cm}| } \hline
    \textbf{Lable} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Q\&A}}\\ \hline
    QA.1\label{QA.1} & Do you think ...?\\ 
    AA.1\label{AA.1} & Yes...\\ 
    QA.2\label{QA.2} & Do you feel?\\ 
    AA.2\label{AA.2} & No...\\ 
    QA.2.a\label{QA.2.a} & "Unexpected Question person A"\\ 
    AA.2.a\label{AA.2.a} & Yes \\
    QA.3\label{QA.3} & What do you think of your previous boss \\
    AA.3\label{AA.3} & He is nice\\
    \hline
   \caption {Results person A} \label{tab:results}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\newpage
\section*{Interview answers person B}
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|c| V{16.5cm}| } \hline
    \textbf{Lable} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Q\&A}}\\ \hline
    QB.1 & Do you think ...?\\ 
    AB.1 & Yes...\\ 
    QB.2 & Do you feel?\\ 
    AB.2 & No...\\ 
    QB.3 & What do you think of your previous boss \\
    AB.3 & He is nice\\
    QB.3.a & "Unexpected Question person B"\\ 
    AB.3.a & Yes \\
    \hline
   \caption {Results person A} \label{tab:results}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The two tables are rather different in almost every respect. What's the purpose of showing the upper one if what you're interested in is creating something like the lower one? Also, you write that you want to "make a table with answers", yet the screenshot shows both questions *and* answers. Please clarify.

Comment: Hey Mico
I can see that my post, does not make a whole lot of sense.
The first picture shows my "interview model", with questions and explanation.
The second picture shows how I want the results from the interviews to be shown and labeled. 
Did that clarify?

Comment: Do you maybe want to delete the entire first half of the posting, including the first screenshot, and rephrase the query ahead of the second screenshot so that it says "I would like to make a table with questions and answers which look like:"? Incidentally, it would be really helfpul if you posted what you've tried so far, LaTeX-wise.

Comment: Please also tell us more about the structure of the table. E.g., how wide should it be? Will questions and answers always alternate, or could some questions have more than one answer?

Comment: @Mico I have edited the text and the code.
I hope it makes more sense know :-)
If not feel free to ask more questions :-)

Comment: "I hope it makes more sense [now]" -- not really, at least not to me. For instance, I still don't understand the relationship between the two tables -- in particular, how (and even if) they depend on each other. Do you want to modify both tables, or just the second one? By the way, using the same letter "A" to denote both "[person] A" and "Answer" [by person A, B, or C...] doesn't exactly enhance clarity either. Maybe somebody else will figure it out?