# Defining labels inside a tabular environment

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, labels

I am using a macro to define certain labels inside a tabular environment, however when I refer to these labels later the displayed text is the section number instead of the desired label.

What's the easiest way to achieve the desired result?  (See code below for the precise situation.)

One solution which I don't like: passing the label name into the "FOOFOO" macro.  I don't necessarily want to give labels to all my FOOFOOs

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{F\arabic{foo}}
\newcommand{\FF}{
  \refstepcounter{foo}\textbf{\thefoo}
}

\newenvironment{footab}{\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}\hline}{\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\FOOFOO}[2]{%
\FF & \textbf{#1} & #2 \\\hline%
}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\label{sec:my-section}

\begin{footab}
\FOOFOO{One}{First example}\label{foo:first}
\FOOFOO{Two}{Second example \label{foo:second}}
\end{footab}

Now I write some stuff referring to \ref{foo:first} (should be F1) and
\ref{foo:second} (should be F2).

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Answers to [Reference table row in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356815/reference-table-row-in-latex) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the cell containing `\refstepcounter` ends, the value of `\@currentlabel` is lost and the previous one is restored.

You can set the label as optional argument to `\FOOFOO`, instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{F\arabic{foo}}
\newcommand{\FF}{%
  \refstepcounter{foo}\textbf{\thefoo}%
}

\newenvironment{footab}{\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}\hline}{\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\FOOFOO}[3][]{%
  \FF#1 & \textbf{#2} & #3 \\\hline
}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\label{sec:my-section}

\begin{footab}
\FOOFOO[\label{foo:first}]{One}{First example}
\FOOFOO[\label{foo:second}]{Two}{Second example}
\FOOFOO{Three}{Third example}
\end{footab}

Now I write some stuff referring to \ref{foo:first} (should be F1) and
\ref{foo:second} (should be F2).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be more careful with `%` at end of lines; you had one that wasn't necessary and missed two, instead.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Could you elaborate on what you mean about the "% at the end of lines"?  (Or point me to somewhere which gives details?)