# Generate a continuosly numbered reference to e.g. a requirement

Tags: cross-referencing, cref

I want to create a table with requirements for a project.

```
   \begin{table}[H]
      \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{0.1}L{0.75}C{0.15}}
         \toprule
            \textbf{R\hyp{}ID} & \textbf{Requirement Description} & \textbf{Priority} \\
         \midrule
            R1 & Requirement 1 & 1 \\
            R2 & Requirement 2 & 1 \\
         \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
      \caption{Ziele}
      \label{tab:goals}
   \end{table}
```

What I wish to do now is, that the R1, R2 are labelled and can be referenced from the text with e.g. `\cref{requirement-1}`.

The command to create the R1 / R2 entries should be customizable: `\uniqueReference{requirement}{R}` where `requirement` would be the label prefix and `R` the text prefix.

```
   \begin{table}[H]
      \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{0.1}L{0.75}C{0.15}}
         \toprule
            \textbf{R\hyp{}ID} & \textbf{Requirement Description} & \textbf{Priority} \\
         \midrule
            \uniqueReference{requirement}{R} & Requirement 1 & 1 \\
            \uniqueReference{requirement}{R} & Requirement 2 & 1 \\
         \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
      \caption{Ziele}
      \label{tab:goals}
   \end{table}
```

Is there a package which does this already? Or would I have to create a custom command?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer.

First, check this question about [Reference table row in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356815/reference-table-row-in-latex).

user31729 used a counter for both rows and cols.
If you want a global unique ref counting, just remove the resetting mechanism at each start of environment aka `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{rowcntr}{0}}`

You then could just define a new counter, such as:

```
\newcounter{rowcntr}
\renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\arabic{rowcntr}}

% A new columntype to apply automatic stepping
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rowcntr}}c}
```

I hope this accomplishes what you wanted to do.
Here is the MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[top=2.81cm, bottom=2.75cm,right=2cm, left=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

\newcounter{rowcntr}
\renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\arabic{rowcntr}}

% A new columntype to apply automatic stepping
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rowcntr}}c}

% Reset the rowcntr counter at each new tabular
%\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{rowcntr}{-1}}



\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \caption{Table with questions} \label{tab:Q1}
        \begin{tabular}{|N|c|l|l|}
            \hline
              Theory & Question                         & Explanation                  \\ \hline
            \label{que:whyisit}           B    & Why is it you think ...          & This is a good question      \\
            \label{que:doyouthink}        A    & Do you think  ...                & This Is also a good question \\
            \label{que:isitcorrect}       B    & is it correct that you think ... & This is question             \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
    Question \ref{que:whyisit} is about ... \\
    Question \ref{que:doyouthink} is about ... \\
    Question \ref{que:isitcorrect} is about ... 
    
    
    \newpage
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Table with questions} \label{tab:Q2}
    \begin{tabular}{|N|c|l|l|}
        \hline
        Theory & Question                         & Explanation                  \\ \hline
        \label{que:whyisit2}           B    & Why is it you think ...          & This is a good question      \\
        \label{que:doyouthink2}        A    & Do you think  ...                & This Is also a good question \\
        \label{que:isitcorrect2}       B    & is it correct that you think ... & This is question             \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Question \ref{que:whyisit2} is about ... 
Question \ref{que:doyouthink2} is about ...
Question \ref{que:isitcorrect2} is about ... 
\end{document}
```